# Get data from another table in mysql with a variable and display it

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, format

What I am trying to achieve is where "alarmtype" is, display text that I can retrieve from another table in my database. Currently, it is displaying a variable. Here is my code

```
<?php
    foreach($db->getEvents() as $event)
    {

        echo "<div class='card'>";
        echo "<div class='card-body'>";
        echo "<h6 class='card-title'>Alarm Number: " . $event->alarmnumber . " Date: " . $event->newdate . "</h6>";
        echo "<h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted'>" . $event->alarmtype . "</h6>";
        echo "<p class='card-text'>Location: " . $event->location . "</p>";
        echo "<a href='#' class='card-link'>Modify Alarm</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

I need to take the alarmtype variable and call another sql where it will pull the text I have store in the database to replace the variable. I hope I explained that well enough.

**EDIT**

```
public function getEventByID()
{
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM alarms T1 INNER JOIN calltype T2 ON T1.alarmtype = T2.id");
    return $this->query($sql)->fetchObject();
}
```

I added this code to my SQL, it loads fine however does not display the text. I also updated

```
echo "<h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted'>" . $event->alarmtype . "</h6>";
```

to

`echo "<h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted'>" . $event->type . "</h6>";`

No luck yet. I ran the sql command and it links both databases together.

Comment: You can use an `INNER JOIN` query in `SQL` to fetch the data corresponding to a column value. Read more about it in the [docs](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

Comment: yes you explained it good, but you didn#t add your select statement the table descriptions.

Comment: I updated my main post, I could not figure out how to add code tags to a comment.

Comment: checkl the statement with inner join in phpmyadmin and see what columns and data you get.

Comment: @nbk I get every column in the first table, then the 2 columns in the other table.

Comment: I figured it out, I was calling getEvents() instead of getEventByID() in my foreach loop. Now to figure out how to get the date to display propely so its m/d/y